# Отменить перемещение к якорю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть якорь. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на соответственную ссылку, хеш в адресную строку добавлялся, а физический скрол осуществляться не должен.
Вот то что нашел на просторах интернета и сколотил в одно.
Работает с багами.
Есть более универсальное решение?

```
$('a[href^="#img"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': window.pageYOffset});
        window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: Зачем нужно реализовывать такое поведение?